# Can I target CSS styles with specific parameters?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Is it possible to use CSS's @media query to target specific styles using a paremeter taken from a database using mysql. I have seen and used this for targeting different styles depending on screen size but could I do this for something in a database for example.

CSS - two different layouts

```
.div{
   width:100%;
   float:none;
}
.div_two{
   width:100%;
   float:none;
}
.div{
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
.div_two{
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
```

As you can see the two divs (div and div_two) are either stacked on top of each other or side by side. But I winder is is possible to take the layout from a database using php and then decide which way to apply the divs.

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM pages WHERE page = '$page'");
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$layout = $results['layout'];
$div = $results['div'];
$div_two = $results['div_two'];
echo '<div class="div">'.$div.'</div><div class="div_two">'.$div_two.'</div>';
```

Something that would automatically sort out the layout of the page would simplify things a lot (if this is possible with PHP) or is the only way around this to add this script to the head of the document and create separate style sheets for each layout?

```
if($layout == 1){
   echo 'style sheet 1';
}else if($layout == 2){
   echo 'style sheet 2';
}else{
   echo 'default style sheet';
}
```

I don't see a problem with this method but a cleaner way of targeting individual styles within the same CSS document would be better.

Comment: Yes it is possible to do the same..,or in my point of view use two different style-sheet and call it as per the requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class on the body, or just separate the sheets.

---

In the first case, you CSS would look like this:

```
.type1 .div{
   width:100%;
   float:none;
}
.type1 .div_two{
   width:100%;
   float:none;
}
.type2 .div{
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
.type2 .div_two{
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
```

And you can use PHP to specify the body class: `<body class="<?php echo $selectedClass; ?>">`

---

And in the other case, you'd use PHP to choose which CSS file to load:

```
if($layout == 1){
    $css = 'css1';
}else if($layout == 2){
    $css = 'css2';
}else{
    $css = 'default';
}
```

And then: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $css; ?>.css">`.

---

The method you choose depends on the amount of differences between the sheets - if there are just a few, method one is ok, but if you're trying to show a completely different presentation in each, use method two and make as many CSS files as needed (you might consider having one common CSS, and the other would be one of the specific ones).

Just try and let CSS drive your presentation looks instead of PHP.

Comment: Yeah didn't think of using a body class, but that definitely looks cleaner then having multiple CCS documents. I'm guessing this simplicity works better for simple layout changes like in the post

Comment: Yes, there's always a battle between the file size vs. the number of files... and there's almost never a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has no logic processing, it won't know which layout you want to use. The browser will simply interpret both layouts together, and render whichever rules take precedence.

Your code snippet at the bottom of the question (loading in a different stylesheet depending on which layout you wish to render) is going to be the way to do this. You can either handle it server-side with PHP (decided as page is rendered) or client-side with Javascript (user can toggle between layouts without refreshing page).